gvfsd-network error
When I start system-config-printer, or when I click on network in Thunar, I get this error message:
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_new_intern: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_new_intern: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_new_intern: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_new_intern: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_release: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_ref_string_release: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_file_info_set_content_type: assertion 'content_type != NULL' failed
Apr 29 20:12:39 I-NET gvfsd-network[5425]: g_file_info_set_content_type: assertion 'content_type != NULL' failed

Is there a way to fix this?
